# Protractor Tests Assign Window Objects

Tags: angularjs, protractor, chromium-embedded

I'm using [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) to run an AngularJS application. CefSharp has a method to `RegisterJsObject`, which assigns objects or properties onto the `window` before any of the client scripts execute.

I would love to be able to test this functionality with Protractor, but I'm not sure how I can access the `window` and assign objects before any of my tests run. Since my application *depends* on those objects being registered to the `window` I need a way to either hard-code this or mock it, without the objects registered, my application continues to throw `undefined` errors.

Is it even possible to access the `window` from Protractor? Something ideal would look something like:

```
describe('my test', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        window.foo = "bar";
    });

    it('should do stuff', function () {
        browser.get('index.html');
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: I have tried

```
describe('my test', function () {
    it('should do stuff', function () {
        browser.executeScript('return window.foo = { bar: {a: "b"}}').then(function () {
        browser.get('#/');
        browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
    });
});
```

But when the window actually loads I'm still seeing `cannot read property 'bar' of undefined`.

**EDIT 2**: Even tried `executeAsyncScript` with no luck.

```
describe('my test', function () {
it('should do stuff', function () {
        browser.executeAsyncScript(function(cb) {
            window.foo = { bar: { a: "b" } };
            cb(true);
        }).then(function (cb) {
            browser.get('#/');
            browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
            browser.wait(function () {
                element(by.id('some-element')).isPresent();
            });
            expect(element(by.id('some-element')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the objects on `window` are being cleared when a new URL is loaded. You'll have to revert to using plain old webdriver for navigating to the URL:

```
describe('my test', function () {
it('should do stuff', function () {
  browser.driver.get('youraddress');
  browser.executeScript(function() {
      window.foo = { bar: { a: "b" } };
  });
  browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
  browser.wait(function () {
    element(by.id('some-element')).isPresent();
  });
  expect(element(by.id('some-element')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: I thought that may be happening, however, the above still seems to throw the same `undefined` error. It seems that Angular is executing between the `browser.driver.get()` and the `browser.executeScript`. Is there anyway to delay Angular in between those two to confirm the window object is actually registered? `driver.get()` doesn't seem to have the timeout parameter that `browser.get()` has, according to the API docs.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
var originalDriverGet = browser.driver.get;
browser.driver.get = function() {
    return originalDriverGet.apply(this, arguments).then(runScript);
};

function runScript() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        browser.executeScript("script to execute...");
    });
}
```

Do this in protractor.conf.js in `onPrepare` block.